# How do I update inline views in Couchdb lite

Tags: android, ektorp, couchdb-lite

I'm using the CouchDbRepositorySupport class available in the ektorp library. According to their documentation I should be able to set a system property that will automatically generate my inline views which I'm doing `System.setProperty(CouchDbRepositorySupport.AUTO_UPDATE_VIEW_ON_CHANGE, Boolean.TRUE.toString());` but it doesn't seem like the views are changing when I edit my existing views. How would I be able to edit views after my app is released? (right now I'm uninstalling and re-installing which is less than ideal)

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems like the view definition is being updated but the view isn't being re-indexed so the changes to the view are not represented

Answer (score 0):

So the solution for me was to check if the view definition was updated and then delete the index of the view that was changed so that everything will be re-indexed.